I2C line crashes on the STM32F091 and won't recover
I'm having a strange behavior on my I2C line that drives a VL53L1X sensor.
I have an STM32F091 microcontroller with the I2C line connected as the schema below to a VL53L1X. The I2C line is more then 3m long, that's why there are level shifters and noise protection chips.
For some reason, after some time, the I2C stops to work. Both lines go high and not even clocking 10 times the clock line makes it restart.
I've tried to turn off the I2C line, using the XSHUT line to put the sensor in a state of hardware idle but nothing makes the I2C restart. The only solution is to switch off the sensor and reboot it.
I'm starting to suspect that there's some sort of hardware issue but I can't figure out what.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This is what the oscilloscope sees when the I2C stops working. You can see on the right side that the I2C stays stuck high for no reason. Also, the I2C HAL on the microcontroller returns Error 4 when the microcontroller tries to transmit


What drives the EN lines of each PCA9507?

@LiorBilia it's not connected

What mean I2C stops to work ?

@MichalDudka please see more info on my question for clarification. It actually stays stuck HIGH

Check all three separated SDA/SCL signals (uC, sensor, line) to check who drive lines high.

What is the meaning of Error 4 from the I2C HAL on the microcontroller? Also where is the oscilloscope connected to in terms of the level shifters and noise protection ICs?

The SCL seems to have a very rapid rise to 5V unlike the normal SCL edges. The SDA is 50V/div, please make sure you use 10x probe setting   correctly on probe and scope. How are the other wires between the level shifters, how is ground and supply going between the 3m distance?

@Justme beside the wrong multiplier on the probe (it's clearly a x10), I'm measuring at the end of the I2C line, before the level shifter. The entire circuit is battery powered so, the GND is shared between the whole electronic to the - pole of the battery

@ChesterGillon it is ACK failure from the device

As per I2C specification, the bus capacitance should not be higher than 200pF for fast mode. Personally I would eliminate the level shifter and simply connect the bus with CAT 5 cable which by spec must have have capacitance less than 52pf/m, with 2.2k pull-up and running at 100kHz (or lower speed), it might well within the I2C spec. But honestly, this application should really use CAN or RS485.

Again. It looks like that someone stops I2C frame "violently". It can be your MCU (imagine stupid firmware which takes control over SDA and SCL and manualy drive them to High), but it can also be one of PCA9507. You need to made another measurment to check who is originator of your issue. Is it MCU on its I2C_SCL_uC signal ? Or is it left one PCA9507 on I2C_SCL_LINE ? Or right one PCA ? Just simply check all three SCL signals in your circuit and look who is originator (with 4 channel scope its pretty easy).

@MichalDudka what signal should I see to come to a conclusion that it's the I2C_SCL_uC or the PCA9507?

@NicoCaldo Anything different then on I2C_SCL_LINE. It's much easier to measure it and draw conclusions based on that than to discuss what you can see there and what it might mean if it were there.
